# Build HTML from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML table which is built in the following way:-

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Party</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Chamber</th> <th>District</th> <th>State</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr dir-paginate="user in users|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10"> 
            <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
            <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
            <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Is it possible to create this table from javascript and in the HTML I just create a div and append the created table from javascript into this div. I tried placing the above content in a javascript variable and do an append but it did not work out. Is there a way to do this?? I think it did not work out may be because of the Angular JS variables. Correct me if I am wrong. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Look into `$compile`.

Comment: It's definitely possible, look at `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild` for example.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Especially in angular?

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS use `<div ng-bind-html="html-var"></div>` and save the html-code in `$scope.html-var`.

For that you need to include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>`